# How to have Scanner and Timer run at the same time

Tags: java

I am trying to make a rotating password program, the issue I am running into is when the program asks for the digits of the password, the timer will stop. I think I could separate the program into 2 operational files and a main file, I would not like to go this route though.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

'''

```
if(i == 10)
        {
            System.out.println("New Passcode: ");
            i = -1;
            d = 0;
            passCode.clear();
            Attempt.clear();
            for(int j = 1; j <= 9;j++)
      {
         Random rand = new Random();
         int upperbound = 10;
         int keycode = rand.nextInt(upperbound);
         passCode.add(keycode);
         x++;
      }
         System.out.println(passCode);
         
         //This is the password input
         
               for(int f = 1; f <= 9;f++)
      {
         d++;
         System.out.println("Input one digit at a time; You are on digit " + d);
         int passAtt = input.nextInt();
         Attempt.add(passAtt);
      }
      System.out.println(Attempt);
        }
        else{
            i++;
            System.out.println("Timer: " + i + " Seconds");
        }
        while(x >= 1)
        {
            if(passCode.equals(Attempt))
        {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("ACCESS GRANTED");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        }
    }
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using an integer to mark the seconds. Instead, create a variable to store the start time. Then subtract that from the current time whenever you want to get the elapsed time. For example, use [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())

Here's a simple class you can use to keep track of the elapsed time:

```
class StopWatch
{
    protected long startTime;
    protected long endTime;
    protected boolean running = false;
    
    public void start()
    {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        running = true;
    }
    public void stop()
    {
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        running = false;
    }
    public double getElapsedSeconds()
    {
        if (running) {
            return (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0;
        }
        else  {
            return (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0;
        }
    }
}
```

And example usage:

```
StopWatch st = new StopWatch();
st.start();
Thread.sleep(1000);  // Simulate long-running operation
System.out.println(st.getElapsedSeconds());
Thread.sleep(5500);  // Another long-running operation
st.stop();
System.out.println(st.getElapsedSeconds());;
```

And the output will be something like:

```
1.0
6.514
```